# Clear listview content?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a little problem with `ListView`. How do I clear a `ListView` content, knowing that it has a custom adapter?

`edit` -
the custom adapter class extends `BaseAdapter`, it looks like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public MyAdapter(Activity a, String[] str) {
        activity = a;
        data = str;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = view;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowa, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text= v.findViewById(R.id.dexter);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = v.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(data[position]);

        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 204, accepted):

**Simply write**

```
listView.setAdapter(null);
```

Comment: Better use Adapter.clear() and Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: in cases anyone still uses android 1.6, it will crash when setting a null or 0 length adapter.

Comment: this works great. who would use android 1.6 still =P thanks mike

Comment: beshkenadze - you got me all exited with `Adapter.clear()`... just too bad that *doesn't exist* ! :/

Comment: If you are extending from `ListFragment` use preferably `setListAdapter(null);`

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere: It is not a call to the 'Adapter' class but to the adapter instance originally used to populate the listView. So basically: my_adapter.clear().

See answer from Maragues for a more clear description.

Answer (score 56):

I guess you passed a List or an Array to the Adapter. If you keep the instance of this added collection, you can do a

```
collection.clear();
listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

this'll work only if you instantiated the adapter with *collection* and it's the same instance.

Also, depending on the Adapter you extended, you may not be able to do this. *SimpleAdapter* is used for static data, thus it can't be updated after creation.

PS. not all Adapters have a *clear()* method. *[ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)* does, but *[ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)* or *[SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html)* don't

Comment: i'm extending BaseAdapter and i think it hasn't clear() method.

Comment: Do you need it to be a BaseAdapter? If you could switch to extending an ArrayAdapter, you would get the clear() method. Looks like in BaseAdapter you need to use this registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer), I guess it'll update automatically if the DataSet changed. But, ArrayAdapter will probable make things easier. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for help but can you give me a sample code on how to extend ArrayAdapter. thanks.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass It's really simillar to what you already have.

Comment: thanks for sharing but i seems that my problem isn't related to the adapter, because even when i use the ArrayAdapter's clear() and i reload the activity, the previous content remains there in addition to the new content. i'm in real trouble. (Sorry for bad english, i hope you get the point).

Comment: Do you override the adapter data set or the adapter after creating it? That is, do you re assign the instances you used to add the adapter to the list? If these instances change, the connection between the adapter, the listview and the screen may fail.

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it, can you please explain more!

Comment: it wasn't a n adapter problem, it's XML parsing problem. thaks a lot guys for help.

Answer (score 8):

It's simple .First you should clear your collection and after clear list like this code :

```
 yourCollection.clear();
 setListAdapter(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Android versions M and N, following works for me and would be the correct approach. Emptying the ListView or setting the Adapter to null is not the right approach and would lead to null pointer issue, invalid ListView and/or crash of the app.

Simply do:

```
    mList.clear();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

i.e. first you clear the list altogether, and then let the adapter know about this change. Android will take care of correctly updating the UI with an empty list. In my case, my list is an ArrayList.

In case you are doing this operation from a different thread, run this code on the UI thread:

```
    runOnUiThread(mRunnable);
```

Where mRunnable would be:

```
    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mList.clear();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple its works me:)**

```
YourArrayList_Object.clear();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate little bit.

Comment: ArrayList<DetailsForCallhistoryListActivity> callhistory_details_list; using this arraylist object  (i.e callhistory_details_list) .  callhistory_details_list.clear();   hope it will help u. let me know any queries

Answer (score 0):

Remove your items from your custom adapter and call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Comment: using notifyDataSetChanged() has no effect on listview contend.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for the duplicate entry in listview.
You have to declare the `onBackPress()`-method on your activity and write down the highlight code given below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    **

    attendence_webdata.clear(); list.setAdapter(null);
    --------------------------------------------------

    **
 }
```

Comment: LOL, of course not, what duplicate entry are you talking about ? What does onBackPressed has to do with clearing adapters ? Do you even know what you are talking about ?

Comment: Sry for my english but when i click button and open screen for list view every time it come with same entry so use clear method in back press

Answer (score -1):

Just put the code `ListView.Items.Clear();` on your method

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: is there such a thing as Items on ListView?

Answer (score -3):

Call `clear()` method from your custom adapter .

Comment: clean() is not available with BaseAdapter.

Comment: you can also set the listview adapter to null.

Answer (score -4):

You need to call both `clear()` from ArrayAdapter and `notifyDataSetChanged()` both.

Below is link 
[click](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/46/)