# pass a text file to an arrayadapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

My question is as follows. I would like to be able to read a text file into an array adapter. I have one TextView and 3 RadioButtons. So far I have managed to pass a string array which can be used to update the TextView. I have an array list as shown below

```
ArrayList<info> list = new ArrayList<info>();

    for(int i=1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Reader reader = new ResultsReader("C:/Users/ALEXDEV/workspace/Questions/src/quiz"+i+".txt");
        reader.read();

        String str = ((ResultsReader)reader).getInput();
        String data[] = str.split("<.>");

        info = q new info();
        q.question = data[0];
        q.choice1 = data[2];
        q.choice2 = data[3];
        q.choice3 = data[4];
        list.add(q);
    }

    for(Question qs: list) { 

      System.out.println("Q: "+qs.question); 
        System.out.println("Q: "+qs.choice1); 
        System.out.println("Q: "+qs.choice2); 
        System.out.println("Q: "+qs.choice3);   
    }
```

-

Q: The question
  Q: answer one
  Q: answer two
  Q: answer three

So what i want todo is pass the arraylist to the arrayadapter so I can use the getView method to return the various results

So far I have tried to pass list which is the arraylist to the MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, list);

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private ArrayList<Question> list;
private Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Question> list) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId,list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
     View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic, null);
        }

        Question element = list.get(position);


        if (element!= null) {
            // My layout has only one TextView
            TextView itemView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questionText);

            if (itemView != null) {
                // do whatever you want with your string and long
                itemView.setText(String.format("%s %d", element.question, element.answer));
            }

         }


        return view;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom adapter to feed the listview.

You can create a custom ArrayAdapter (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265712/1105376)) or BaseAdapter (example [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx)).

In either case, you will be overriding the `getView` method of the adapter to process your data into the various widgets in your layout.

**EDIT**

If the question is actually "how do I call the adapter?" then:

```
private CustomAdapter my_adapter;

my_adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row, list);
setListAdapter(my_adapter);
```

And follow one of the links above to create your `CustomAdapter`.

Comment: if i have another question about this question and want to add a comment do i need to untick my answer so people will know it is a question to answer

Comment: It really depends.  We try to keep to a "one question per post" thing here... makes it easier for other people to find help with their specific issues.  You asked about passing a textfile/arraylist into an adapter.  Now if you have a question about implementing the adapter for said array, IMO that would be a new question.  If you thought a solution given would work, and there is some complication so that it wouldn't work, then by all means, un-accept the answer and **edit your question**.  Don't ask more questions in commments, unless it is a followup like "where does that code go exactly?".

Comment: thanks i will remember that keep each particular question i have separate and not just have a large general question.