# Error when creating an Adapter

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-arrayadapter

When I want to set a List of 'PaysItem' containing a String and Bitmap in a ListView.
I'm using a `SherlockListFragment` and i have the error on that line:
`ArrayAdapter<PaysItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PaysItem>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.pays_item,list);`

pays_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="50dip"
android:layout_height="50dip" android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/text_pays"
 android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
 android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The error is:

```
You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
```

The error is clear, I have to supply a TextView ID, but how to solve that?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error :**

> You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

means you need to pass an TextView id  to `ArrayAdapter` . pass it as:

```
ArrayAdapter<PaysItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PaysItem>
        (getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.pays_item,R.id.text_pays,list);
```

Comment: Yes there is no FC no. However, I have a wrong results. but you answered my posted question. Will acecpt in 6 minutes. Thank you man.

Comment: @androniennn : my answer is according to your question but if you want to show images and text in ListView then use SimpleAdapter and Create custom Adapter . see [this](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/listview-simpleadapter/) example which is i think more helpful in your case

Comment: I was trying and opened a new question. What if the images are taken from an URL link? Can a hashmap/list store Drawables and then set them in SimpleAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your own adapter, otherwise you won't see any picture.
Please look here:
[How to use ArrayAdapter<myClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass)