# Passing a list to a custom view?

Tags: java, android, oop

I am trying to make a custom style for android spinner, however there are several problems.
I have noticed in many examples, they pass array to getCustomView method. I am wondering whether I can pass a list instead of an array.

Second problem is why they have declared variable and initialized in class variable scope?
They have declared arrays like this.

```
String []data1={"Brainbitz:java","Brainbitz:Android","Brainbitz:Embedded Systems","Brainbitz:PHP"};
```

in class variable scope. But when I try to do for the list I get an error. why?

Third is,

If we can pass list to getCustomView how do I do that? Here is the link to the tutorial [tutorial](http://easyandroidtutorials.blogspot.com/2012/05/custom-spinner-in-android.html)

I am considering this source code.

```
 public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            label.setText(list3.get(position));

//            TextView sub=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//            sub.setText(data2[position]);
//
//            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//            icon.setImageResource(images[position]);

            return row;
            }
```

In above code I don't know the syntax to pass position to list3 list type reference.

Please be kind enough to explain this.

Comment: please tag android first ,this android question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of All,

You are using **default** `ArrayAdapter` Class..

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>();
```

Which Uses `String` class for data bind. If you want to make an `ArrayAdapter` with a `ArrayList` or `List` you have to make a **Custom Adapter** by extending `ArrayAdapter<Custom_Class>` or `BaseAdapter`.

The `ArrayAdapter` class can handle any Java object as input. It maps the data of this input to a TextView in the layout.

`ArrayAdapter` uses the `toString()` method of the data input object to determine the String which should be displayed.

Look at [How to use ArrayAdapter<myClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass)  and this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

**Update:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
  private List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();

  public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                        List<String> objects) {
  super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  listString  = objects;
  }

  public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
   View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, parent, false);
   TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   label.setText(listString.get(position)); // How to use listString
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: I am using the tutorial's class which has extended as followes, `public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: Then make a **Constructor** of that **Custom Adapter** class with argument `List<YOUR_CLASS>` and use that object in `getView()` of your custom adapter class..

Comment: Also before using any tutorial just check whether its followed standard android programming rules or not..

Comment: but I am learning, How can I know whether it is standard rule then :)

Comment: As if you know basic java programming rule, You know how to use `Class`, `Constructor` and `Member Variables`. As Most of Tutorials are for just workaround behind the Programming rules..

Comment: another comment, what do you think of initializing arrays in class variable scope? Can't I do this for list. Sorry for asking this kind of questions

Comment: I had to create a custom style for spinner becase default spinner doesnt behave as I want

Comment: My last comment, If I have several spinners such as let's say 3 spinners do I have to create 3 Adaptor classes? I have to passe list to  `label.setText(list3.get(position));` . isn't there more easy way to handel?

Comment: That's why we use `Adapter Class`.. If your 3 spinners have the **Same UI** only display data will be changed then the follow my answer. You don't need to create a 3 different Adapters. Just pass 3 different **ArrayList** to Adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected solution,

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<String> objects) {
              super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
              // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
            @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            label.setText(list3.get(position));

//            TextView sub=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//            sub.setText(data2[position]);
//
//            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//            icon.setImageResource(images[position]);

            return row;
            }

   }
```

Basiclly, I had done 1 mistake, one is I hadnt initalised constructor correctly.

Comment: One more thing your programing code is wrong. As you are not using List<String> objects in your `MyAdapter` then whats the need of using it in Constructor... :-)

Comment: If you are using static `List<String> objects` Class level variables then no need to pass it to `MyAdapter` Constructor.