# how to initialize my BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, initialization, baseadapter

Here is my constructor for my custom BaseAdapter

```
public MyAdapterAds(Activity activity, BaseAdapter delegate) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.delegate = delegate;
}
```

I have an arraylist of objects named mObjects. How do I get them into this method from my activity?

How do I initialize my baseAdapter

this is what I tried

```
 myAdapter = new myAdapterAds(MainActivity.this, new ArrayAdapter<myObject>(context, R.layout.my_object_cell, myObjectArray));
```

No reason for this to work, but I had just began rewriting this baseadapter, how would I rewrite that last part to get my array of objects in it?

I keep getting "IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource to be a textview" but I am using an object with several parameters, why would I display a textview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason your adapter is not a subclass of `BaseAdapter`? Typically you want to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265712/832776

The reason for the warning is that the default `ArrayAdapter` constructor expects the layout to only contain one `TextView`; so I would check `my_object_cell.xml` is valid. If you're planning to have multiple `TextView`s or different widgets then you can use `setViewBinder()` to assign properties from your object to each view, along with the `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

---

```
           ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ls.setAdapter(adapter);
```

public class **ExampleAdapter** extends **BaseAdapter** {
        ViewHolder holder;

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }


        holder.name.setText("name");


        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        private TextView name;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```