# ListView is not showing on Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

How can I put a ListView into a fragment?
I'm Trying with getview() but it is not working. Help me please.

My array is Mail with attribute type string, the code compile without errors.

I do not understand

My Class fragment1 is

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
private ListView list;
LayoutInflater inflater1;
ViewGroup container1;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState) {
    this.inflater1=inflater;
    this.container1=container;
   return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View view = this.inflater1.inflate(R.layout.list_items,this.container1, false);
    list= (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);

list.setAdapter(new Adapter2 (this));

}

public class Adapter2 extends ArrayAdapter Mail {

private Activity mcontext;
private Correo[] mvalues;
public Adapter2(Fragment context) {
    super(context.getActivity(),R.layout.simple_item,Mail);
    this.mcontext= (Activity) context.getActivity();
    this.mvalues= Mail; // My array list 
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = mcontext.getLayoutInflater();
    View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_item,null);
    TextView lblDe = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.textViewlabel);
    lblDe.setText(mvalues[position].getText());
    TextView lblDe2 = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.textViewlabel2);
    lblDe2.setText(mvalues[position].getText());
    return(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ListView and Fragments does not work like that.

1) `onCreateView` is the method where you specify the `View` that will be shown in the fragment.  So `onActivityCreated` is not the right one.

2) See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass) how `ArrayAdapter` work. However I would recommend you to use `BaseAdapter` class if you want to show your own `View` for each list item.

Comment: thnks. ok .. 'll see the example.