# Custom list clicking with checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I have one list that contain some check box, how can find out which check box is clicked.
I try itemClickListener() but not response to me,

Comment: `onItemClickListener` is set on the whole row view of ListView, you have to distinguish clicks on checkboxes, so that your row click listeners wont interfere. http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: I am try to add with Cursor, but in this example use list.add()

Comment: http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have create your own adapter by extendind the [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class
then in the getview() method of that adpater inflate the Layout and get the checkbox and write the listener for that..

Answer (score 0):

Create you own ArrayAdapter and, inside you getView(...) method implement yout ckeckbox listener.

getView gives you the item position in the list so you can do whatever you need.

here is an exemple of how to create you onw arrayadapter:

[How to use ArrayAdapter<myClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = MyPINsActivity.this
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_mypins, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb);
       //here you can save the position as tag to CheckBox, and get where you want
        cb.setTag(position);

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                  //get the positon of CheckBox by using mCheckBox.getTag()
                    String positon = cb.getTag().toString();
                    Log.e(TAG, "positon: "+positon);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```