# getting data using volley from JSON to listview with custom arrayadapter

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

this is my code and it's working good.
i want to get multiple values (including image address) from my JSON data and show them in each row of my listview but i couldn't do that i just could get one data (title) and put that in simple list, how i can replace ***android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1*** with my own single row layout? i'm new to android and i couldn't understand wheres the loop of listviews and rows.

what i wanna do is get some datas from JSON and show them in my custom row layout, something like google plus list view, with images, title and description

sorry for my bad english:)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_restaurants);
    restaurantList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurantList);


    final ArrayAdapter<String> restaurantAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,restaurantArray);
    restaurantList.setAdapter(restaurantAdapter);

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,feedURL,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray restaurants = response.getJSONArray("posts");
                        for (int i =0; i<restaurants.length(); i++){
                            restaurantArray.add(restaurants.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    restaurantAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            },new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });


    rq.add(jsonrequest);
}
```

Comment: hi, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is default by android system and can have only one textview in it.replace it with your own layout that can have more than one textview and inflate it

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried to do this multiple times, i made my own layout for row but i don't know where and how to get data and set text (and or image src) to my layout items

Comment: Create a class extending ArrayAdapter and override the getView method to inflate your custom row

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ArrayAdapter<myClass>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this tutorial to create arrayadapter and use it in your program

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

it even implements View Holder pattern.