# show contacts saved in phone on screen as a list

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, listview

i am trying to access contacts stored in phone(both number and name) which i have done successfully now i want to display them them in a list such that both contact name and  number should appear as a single list item  i have following code not running anyone please tell whats the problem

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

mainActivity.java

```
 package com.tayyab.contactnum;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.ContactsContract;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.ContentResolver;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listview;
    List<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
 String name=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                  newValues.add(name);
        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur
.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+ " = " + id, 

             null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones
    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                }

                phones.close();
            }
        }
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newValues));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
    }
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using,

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newValues));
```

you must use:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newValues);
    listview.setAdapter(aa);
```

and just after newValues.add(name) you must use

```
aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make a class to hold the information you require instead of using an `ArrayList<String>`, make an `ArrayList<Person>` and define the `Person` class as:

```
class Person {

    public final String name, phone;

    public Person(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

Now, as you go through the cursor, create instances of `Person` and add them to the `ArrayList<Person>`.

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265712/772095 for an example of how you should extend `ArrayAdapter` with your new custom type `Person` and you can create views for your list items that way.

```
public class PersonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person>
```