# how the save stories on the CNN Android App works?

Tags: android, saving-data

On the CNN Android App, there is a feature for saving a news content/story to the phone, so that the user can access these saved stories when not connected to the internet (ie, in an offline mode).. I am also trying to do something similar on my android news app... please how do I go about this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets do that )

**1.** You should create `MySQLiteLoader.class` that will be extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` to save and load `newsItems`.

**2.** SQLite database contains columns such : Title, subtitle, description, image (BLOB), other.

**3.** Add `saveSingleNew()` method. `FeedItem.class` - example class that will contains your news.

Example :

```
public void addSite(FeedItem site){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, site.getTitle()); // title
    values.put(KEY_SUB_TITLE, site.getSubTitle()); // subtitle
    values.put(KEY_DATE, site.getDate()); // date
    values.put(KEY_IMG, site.getImg()); // img to byte[]
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, site.getSubTitle()); //  description

    db.close();
}
```

**4.** Create `getAllNews()` method.

Example :

```
public List<FeedItem> getAllNews() {

    List<FeedItem> items = new ArrayList<>();


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NEWS, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setItemId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))); //Item id.
            item.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            item.setSubTitle(cursor.getString(2));
            item.setDate( cursor.getString(3));
            byte [] b = cursor.getBlob(1);
            Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length));
            item.setDrawableId(image);
            item.setImageBlob(cursor.getString(4));
            item.setDescription(cursor.getString(5)); // description.

            items.add(item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return news list
    return items;

}
```

**5.** Make an `MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<FeedItems>);` to show our news in list.

Example: [Custom list adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass)

Use `getAllNews()` method to get your saved news array list into custom adapter.

Add `SAVE` button.

**6.** Enjoy your app )