# Add multiple ListView lists in one single layout in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to add 3 or more lists in a layout xml. I didn't expect this to be a problem, but I don't see all the lists(and they get populated) and the view does not scroll. I need an opinion to what stupid stuff I am doing here, please.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/googleDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigationHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Search" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:text="Hello, user"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:text="description"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollojt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/navigationHeader"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#1f000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionsTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
                android:text="@string/questions_label"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawerList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/questionsTitle"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/appsTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/drawerList"
                android:text="@string/apps_label"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawerList2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appsTitle"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/groupsTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/drawerList2"
                android:text="@string/groupapps_label"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawerList3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/groupsTitle"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dmTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/drawerList3"
                android:text="@string/directapps_label"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawerList4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dmTitle"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You cannot put listviews inside scrollViews

Comment: I tried without a ScrollView, it does the same thing.

Comment: you also cant have listviews wrap content

Comment: if you are trying to get 3 lists one after another that is the wrong approach. you should have one listview and have logic in the custom adapter to know what row it should be displaying

Comment: or you should look into expandableListViews they might be what you are looking for

Comment: Do you really need 3 ListView? or can you use ArrayAdapter. I can help you with a XML based on yours but the best approach is what @Tomer Shemesh said.

Comment: i am thinking now how to do this and use just one ListView. I have three type of objects i want to list nicely.

Comment: Ok use an ArrayAdapter, Im gonna give you an answer with a link where you can found how to

Answer (score 0):

Use just one ListView with an ArrayAdapter.

[how to use arrayadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass)

If you need help customizing the array adapter, just search on google or ask me ;)