# getView() method is not called in custom adapter with gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

When I debug the code, it is calling constructors in InviteListAdapter but it is not calling getView() method.  I have tried multiple solutions available on stackoverflow but none of them works. Hope any one can find the mistake or solution for this.

```
invitableFriends.size()
```

returns value greater than 0.

**InviteListAdapter**

```
public class inviteListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {

private final Context context;
private final List<JSONObject> invitableFriends;
private ImageView profilePicView;

public inviteListAdapter(Context context, List<JSONObject> invitableFriends) {
    super(context, R.layout.invite_adapter, invitableFriends);
    this.context = context;
    this.invitableFriends = invitableFriends;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invite_adapter, parent, false);

    profilePicView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.inviteListItemProfilePic);
    TextView nameView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.inviteListItemName);

    JSONObject currentUser = invitableFriends.get(position);

    nameView.setText(currentUser.optString("first_name"));


    return listItemView;
}

 }
```

**first.java**

```
public View onCreateView (
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first,container, false);

    invitesGridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.invitesGridView);

            return view;
}


final inviteListAdapter adapter = new inviteListAdapter(this,inviteFriendList);
    invitesGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: are you sure `setAdapter` is called? when do you call this method?

Comment: You have given `parent` as root and `false` as well, means you provide a parent and tell it not to take it as a parent? use `.inflate(R.layout.invite_adapter, null);` (no root, so it will take xml root as root)
And of course, set your adapter inside `onCreateView` as that's where you are creating the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public View onCreateView (
    LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first,container, false);

invitesGridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.invitesGridView);
final inviteListAdapter adapter = new inviteListAdapter(this,inviteFriendList);
invitesGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return view;
 }
```

Call setAdapter inside onCreateView

Comment: Is it still work if I am passing inviteFriendList null? because I am getting data in it after onCreateView() for that reason I have call setAdapter out of onCreateView.

Comment: No. It will not work. Post your complete code. in which method your are calling setAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to use context class static method. Like, change `context` to `Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not good practice to create `inflater` object in `getView()` method, Instead create one in constructor using `LayoutInflater.from(context);`

This link will help you out
[How to use ArrayAdapter<myClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass)