# Array list checking if value exists, if exists add 1 to string

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, android-gridview

Say i have an Array list called `listitem` which updates every time a `GridView` is clicked.
It gets the item of the `GridView` that was clicked and adds it to the array list, which is also used as the backing array for an adapter of a `ListView`.
That works fine but instead of adding the same rows to the `ListView`, I want to display a message like `item_clicked (2)` when it was clicked twice,
and if its clicked again display `item_clicked (3)` and so on.

I tried to approach this with this code:

```
public void addItems(int position) {
    if (listItems.contains(value.get(position))) {
        int index = listItems.indexOf(value.get(position));
        listItems.set(index,value.get(position)); <- here
    } else {
        listItems.add(value.get(position));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

`position` is the index of the `GridView` and `values` is an array of the values of the `GridView`.

This is my `GridView` code:

```
        int index = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            value.add("ID :" + rs.getString(1) + "  Nombre:" + rs.getString(3));
            list2.add(values.get(index));
            index++;
            Log.w("query result: ", rs.getString(1));
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(papeleta_act.this, R.layout.list_item, list2);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                addItems(position);

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("My error;", e);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any idea of how to approach this prob. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume all items in the `GridView` are of a single type, and let's call it `A`. In this case, the `ArrayList` holds items of type `A`.

`A` simple solution would be to have `listitem` contain objects of a type that wrap `A` and also have a counter, for the times clicked. Possible implementation is:

```
public class B {
    public A mA;
    public int times_clicked;
}
```

How to show the times clicked in the `ListView` depends on your implementation of the layout. The default behavior of an `ArrayAdapter` is to check if the root element of the layout it was given is a `TextView`, and then set its text to the result of the `toString()` function of the item it is showing, so you could add this method to class `B`:

```
public String toString(){
     if(times_clicked == 1 && A != null)
         return A.toString();
     else
         return "item_clicked ("+times_clicked+")";
}
```

Comment: okay, ill try it out just one question.
wouldnt that trigger for all the elements that are going to be added to the list view?

Comment: yes, I edited it a bit. But in general this is a general direction of what you should do. you might still want to show `A.toString()` even when an item was clicked more than once. You might also want to move away from the default behavior eventually, which is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass

Comment: well ill try to implement this, not today tho, i have some stuff to do and complete but ill let you know what happened tomorrow

Comment: not really what i wanted but its a nice workaround and well it works so thanks!