# problems while setting ArrayList<Drawable> with ArrayAdapter<Drawable> in android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

In my app I want to display Application Icons in `Listview`.I am getting application icon by using its package name that package name is stored in `arrayList<String>` variable `arrayPackage`.So,It should be like this:

`ArrayList<Drawable> arrayList=new ArrayList<Drawable>();
        Drawable d=getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(file.toString());
        arrayList.add(d);`

And now I am setting `arrayList` variable with `ListView` adapter like this:

`ArrayAdapter<Drawable> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Drawable>(this,R.layout.iconss,arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);`

where `R.layout.iconss`  is my layout which contains `ImageView`.But it is not working it gives errors in `Logcat` like this:

`07-24 11:53:04.640 27041-27041/com.example.adarsh.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.adarsh.test, PID: 27041
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1196)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1409)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:382)
                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347) 
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270) 
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565) 
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727) 
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537) 
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537) 
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537) 
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436) 
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722) 
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537) 
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2045) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1196) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1409) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084) 
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990) 
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767) 
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580) 
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550) 
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)`

So whats the problem..Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use ArrayAdapter directly then you must have to provide a TextView in your layout. And pass your TextView id into it or make the id of that TextView as `android:id="@android:id/text1"`.

But if you want to use a custom layout which don't have any TextView then you have to implement a Custom Adapter class that extends ArrayAdapter.

You may follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265712/2728085) to know how to implement custom adapter.

Comment: OK that means I want to make custom adapter which will let me use image view in my listView