# Null point Exception while invoking custom adapter : Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I wanted to create a `ListView` in a `Fragment`. I have created a custom adapter for a an array of objects of data type `ArrayList`.

But the app crashes when I launch the activity containing this `Article` fragment.

### Error

```
 12-31 12:01:09.746 25620-25620/com.example.root.talaash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.root.talaash, PID: 25620
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.root.talaash/com.example.root.talaash.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5309)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.root.fragments.ArticleFragment.onCreateView(ArticleFragment.java:40)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6068)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5309) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

### Article class(package : com.example.root.aditional)

```
public class Article {
    String title;
    String author;
    String category;
    String date;
    String url;
    Boolean tag = false;

    public Article(String title, String author, String category, String date, String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.category = category;
        this.date = date;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setTag(Boolean tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

### ArticleAdaper class(package : com.example.root.adapters)

```
public class ArticleAdapter<A> extends ArrayAdapter<Article>{

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title, author, category, date;
    }

    public ArticleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Article> articles) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_article, articles);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_article, parent, false);

            viewHolder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
            viewHolder.author= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.authorText);
            viewHolder.category= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryText);
            viewHolder.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateText);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Article item = getItem(position);
        if(item!= null){
            viewHolder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
            viewHolder.author.setText(item.getAuthor());
            viewHolder.category.setText(item.getCategory());
            viewHolder.date.setText(item.getDate());
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I wrote the above class with the help of reading this question's first answer :
[How to use ArrayAdapter<myClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265661/how-to-use-arrayadaptermyclass)

### The fragment containing the listView(package : com.example.root.project)

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

    public ArticleFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>(6);
        articles.add(new Article("Rose", "Sample Author", "Sample category", "Sample date", "Sample url"));

        ListAdapter articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(this.getContext(), articles);
        ListView listView = (ListView)container.findViewById(R.id.articleListView);
        listView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);

        /*ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.articleListView);*/
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false);
    }
}
```

I am very new to android development and I would like to have a detailed explanation as to where I am going wrong and what I should do to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

**At first return your view** .

Don't

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false);
```

Do

```
return your view ;
```

Then pass **getActivity()**

Example

```
   View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.articleListView);
    ListAdapter articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), articles);
    listView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);

   return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the `ListView` inside wrong `ViewGroup`. Try this -

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false);
ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.articleListView);

return root;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate the view first in your `onCreateView` and then you need to find the `ListView` there instead of `container`. Return the view finally as the last return statement in your `onCreateView`.

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

    public ArticleFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false);

        ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>(6);
        articles.add(new Article("Rose", "Sample Author", "Sample category", "Sample date", "Sample url"));

        ListAdapter articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(this.getContext(), articles);
        ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.articleListView);
        listView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);

        // Return the inflated Fragment here
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false);
    ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>(6);
    articles.add(new Article("Rose", "Sample Author", "Sample category", "Sample date", "Sample url"));

    ListAdapter articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(this.getContext(), articles);
    ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.articleListView);

    listView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);

    /*ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.articleListView);*/
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

you are not getting the listview properly